# Code displaying plugin for a mobile Wordpress blog?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, mobile

Do any wordpress plugins for displaying/formatting source code in a blog work well on mobile devices out of the box?

Comment: What do you mean by 'plugins for displaying source code'? As in a plugin that will allow you to format html/php that you include in your blog posts, or a plugin which will allow you to modify the source of your plugins, themes, etc?

Comment: @m0r7if3r As in "a plugin which will allow your to format html/php for display in my blog posts."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/